# Invertibility of a Toeplitz operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a real-valued function.  I am trying to show that the Toeplitz operator $T_\phi$ is invertible if the function 1 is in the range of $T_\phi$.  Here is what I got so far:

There exists a function $f\in H^2$ such that $T_\phi(f)=1$.  This implies $\phi \bar{f}=1+h$ is in $H^2$.  Then $\phi f\bar{f}=(1+h)f$ is in $H^1$.  Hence $\phi f\bar{f}=\alpha$ for some constant $\alpha$.  So $\phi$ and $\alpha$ have the same sign.  Thus $\phi$ is always positive or always negative.

I do know that $\sigma(T_\phi)=[\operatorname{ess\,inf}(\phi),\operatorname{ess\,sup}(\phi)]$ but I do not know where to go from here.

So I think it boils down to showing that if $\phi$ is always positive or always negative, then essinf$(\phi)$>0 or esssup$(\phi)<0$ respectively.

Comment: If $\sigma(T_{\phi})=[ess inf (\phi), ess sup(\phi)]$, and $\phi$ is always positive or always negative, then $0$ cannot be in the spectrum.

Comment: tht is what I am having trouble showing.  I assume essinf(phi)=0 and I am trying to get a contradiction

Comment: I just got it.  Thanks